# Как реализуется перегрузка [] для std::vector?

Tags: c++

Как реализовать перегрузку оператора [] для std::vector?

Comment: Никак. этот оператор в `std::vector`  не виртуальный

Comment: Разве что влезть в файл `<vector>` и дописать там.